# Semistability under resolution of singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a projective variety over the filed of complex number and $X^s$ be its smooth locus with $X \setminus X^s$ has codimension at least $2$. Let $E$ be a reflexive sheaf on $X^s$. Assume that $i_*E$ is semistable with respect to an ample divisor $A$ on $X$, where $i: X^s \to X$ be the inclusion.  Let $\pi: Y \to X$ be a resolution of singularities of $X$.

Question: Is $\pi^*(i_*E)$ semistable with respect to some ample divisor in $Y$ ?

Comment: In many cases the sheaf $\pi^*(i_*E)$ is even not torsion free.

Comment: What about if $E$ is itself locally free on $X^s$  and $X$ is normal ?

Comment: Even in this case.

Comment: If we consider the sheaf $(\pi^*(i_*E))/Tor$, then can we say about its semistability ?

Comment: Which semistability you are interested in?

Comment: slope semistability with respect to some ample divisor.

Comment: With respect to the ample divisor $\pi^*A - \sum a_iE_i$ for some $a_i \ge 0$, where $E_i'$s are components of the exceptional locus.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that the resolution $\pi \colon Y \to X$ is the identity over $X^s$, so that $X^s \subset Y$. Then the sheaf
$$
E_Y := \pi^*(i_\ast E) / \mathrm{torsion}
$$
is always slope semistable with respect to $\pi^*A$.

Indeed, let $F \subset E_Y$ be a reflexive subsheaf. Then $F\vert_{X^s}$ is a reflexive subsheaf in $E$ and
$$
F_X := i_\ast(F\vert_{X_s}) \subset i_\ast E
$$
is a reflexive subsheaf in $i_\ast E$. Then we have
$$
\mu(F) = 
\frac{1}{r(F)} c_1(F) \cdot (\pi^*A)^{n-1} =
\frac{1}{r(F_X)} c_1(F_X) \cdot A^{n-1} =
\mu(F_X)
$$
and similarly
$$
\mu(E_Y) =
\frac{1}{r(E_Y)} c_1(E_Y) \cdot (\pi^*A)^{n-1} =
\frac{1}{r(i_\ast E)} c_1(i_\ast E) \cdot A^{n-1} = 
\mu(i_\ast E).
$$
Since $i_\ast E$ is slope semistable, we have $\mu(F_X) \le \mu(i_\ast E)$, hence $\mu(F) \le \mu(E_Y)$, and hence $E_Y$ is semistable.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer.

Comment: Is $\pi^*A$ ample ?

Comment: Of course it is not.

Comment: But I want semistability with respect to an ample divisor.  I think $\pi^*A - \sum a_iE_i$ is ample for some $a_i$. Here $E_i's$ are components of the exceptional divisor. Can we say something with respect to this ample divisor ?

Comment: You can try to look at all semisimple subscheaves $F \subset E_Y$ of the same slope $\pi^*A$ as $E_Y$ and try to find $a_i$ such that their $(\pi^*A - \sum a_iE_i)$-slope is less than that.

Comment: Is it always possible to find such $a_i$ such that the $(\pi^*A -\sum a_iE_i)$ slope is less than that of $\pi^*A$ and $(\pi^*A - \sum a_iE_i)$ is ample ?